# $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r

I have a very simple dataset and I tried to perform table() on the first column of the table, but R returns a captioned error message. I searched online but don't quite understand why this would even happen, as R accepts my table as a table... could anyone advise?

My expect output:

```
> table(tab$V1)
  CA 1
  CO 1
  OH 2
```

However it returns:

```
> tabraw
  V1        V2
1 OH Cleveland
2 OH  Columbus
3 CO    Denver
4 CA   SanFran

> tab <- table(tabraw)

> tab
    V2
V1   Cleveland Columbus Denver SanFran
  CA         0        0      0       1
  CO         0        0      1       0
  OH         1        1      0       0

> table(tab$V1)
Error in tab$V1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: What is `class(tab)` and `str(tab)`?

Comment: `V1` is not a column in the table, it's just a label for the rownames below it. The first "column" is the one under "Cleveland". It is accessible via `tab[,1]` or `tab[,'Cleveland']`.

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for

```
table(tabraw$V1)
# 
# CA CO OH 
#  1  1  2
```

The object `tab` is an object of class table and doesn't support the `$` function.

You can also obtain the desired information from the `tab` object with

```
rowSums(tab)
# CA CO OH 
#  1  1  2
```

Answer (score 4):

You should think about table objects as matrices from which the 2D ones do inherit all their indexing properties (so `[ dim-indices ]`):

```
is.matrix(tab)   # returns TRUE
```

If you have a greater then 2d table, it will naturally inherit its accessor functions from the array class. The only (typical data) class that uses "$" as a accessor is list (from which dataframes inherit). Try:

```
tab[ , 1]  # Or
tab[ , "Cleveland"]
```

(I suppose I shouldn't have been so categorical about "$". You can access elements of some language objects and environment objects with that accessor, since they behave as lists.)