# After reading data from the csv (read.csv2) unable to access column data

Tags: r

I am newbie on R-lang, I am debugging the existing script which use to work earlier but doesn't work any more

```
accountInfo=read.csv2(file='AccountInfo.csv', header=T)
accountInfo=accountInfo[accountInfo$Status=='Inactive' | accountInfo$Status=='Closed',]
accountInfo$DV=as.numeric(accountInfo$Status=='Closed')
```

The above code use to work earlier, but now it is giving following error

```
Error in accountInfo$Status : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Any idea - what might have changed here? and how this can be fixed? Also, I have seen other questions like following but they were not helpful here at all.

[$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124801/operator-is-invalid-for-atomic-vectors)

Comment: Any reason why you're using `read.csv2` instead of `read.csv`?  Can you post a few lines of data?

Comment: give us some example of your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because of the drop feature of indexing. Try:

```
accountInfo=read.csv2(file='AccountInfo.csv', header=T)
accountInfo=accountInfo[accountInfo$Status=='Inactive' | accountInfo$Status=='Closed',, drop = FALSE]
accountInfo$DV=as.numeric(accountInfo$Status=='Closed')
```