# cox regression with R atomic vectors error

Tags: r, atomic, cox-regression

I have a dataset imported into R.  I sucessfully ran survfit on the data set.  I have one column with the periods survived by the patient and one column with (0/1) outcome whether the patient survived.  I am know trying to do `coxph()` on the data and am using the following.

```
coxph <- coxph(Surv(mydata$V11, mydata$event), method ="breslow")
```

However, I keep getting the following error.  I have tried using `as.numeric` on the variables but this still does not fix the problem.  I have also tried removing `mydata$` from each variable in the line of code above.  Thank you.

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124801/operator-is-invalid-for-atomic-vectors)

Comment: What happens if you remove `mydata$` from the variable names and add `data=mydata` inside the `coxph()` function call?

Answer (score 0):

1. To prevent this error, you have to explicitly include `"formula ="` in `coxph()`, as shown below.
2. Also, if you're trying to model the null model, you need to include " `~ 1`" after `Surv()`.

```
coxph <- coxph(formula = Surv(mydata$V11, mydata$event) ~ 1, 
               method ="breslow")
```